# Reading huge json file in python

Tags: python, json, memory

I am having trouble reading big JSON file. My file size is around 6GB. I I have already tried ijson to read it like a stream--item by item-- with the  following line:

```
f = open(path, 'rb')
for row in ijson.items(f, 'Row'):  
  //do something
```

and I got "memory error"/"Killed" error from python shell. I think its not a memory issue coz I have enough on my system. around 3GB of swap and 20 GB RAM.

Now I know ijson reads line a stream but my problem is that the whole 6GB file is a single line so jitem.items won't help either. Can anyone please suggest me a solution how can I do this read efficiently without running into memory issues. My JSON looks something like this

```
{Row:[{
    "Cell": [
        {
            "$": "blabla",
            "column": "blala",
            "timestamp": 1494589152912
        },
        {
            "$": "blal bla",
            "column": "blala",
            "timestamp": 1494589152916
        },
    ],
    "key": "blalaa"
}]}
```

Comment: I don't think that's how ijson works.

Comment: I don't think ijson reads the file by lines. It [reads](https://github.com/isagalaev/ijson/blob/master/ijson/backends/python.py#L14) by 16 megabytes blocks.

Comment: Take a look at this post on that topic: https://www.dataquest.io/blog/python-json-tutorial/

Comment: ok but entually the read will finish after the entire file is loaded in memory right? coz otherwise I would be able to iterate in the for loop and would not get the memory error or?

Comment: @jlaur, thanks for the pointer. Unfortunately, this is what I am doing now but it does not work since my entire 6GB json doc is one single line so ijson.items has to load that entire line first and that is where the memory error comes in. But thanks though :)